# Is there a function in SQL Oracle allowing for an aggregate multiplication over a column partition?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, aggregate

I would like to obtain an aggregated multiplication of a number of values, for particular values of a certain column. So in simpler terms, I'd like the set of values 'X' matching identical column values 'Y'

Can anyone help explain the situation or offer a suggestion?

I have tried solving both separately, which was fine, but the combined approach I took did not work, resulting in the error: "00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments" Error.

If the problem were separated into two, the first to my knowledge is solved by using
 `exp(sum(ln(X)))`

while the second is done by
`function(X) over (partition by Y)`

where my combined approach was simply:

`(EXP  (SUM(  LOG(tbl.X)  ) over (partition by tbl.Y))  )`

so for the table

```
Y   X
______
a   2
a   2
b   3
```

the desired output for the new table, where the sought value is Z, should be:

```
Y   X   Z
__________
a   2   4
a   2   4
b   3   3
```

Comment: It works when you use function `ln` instead of `log`.

Comment: You can always write your own aggregate for that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it worked with ```ln```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `LN( value )` function not the `LOG( base, value )` function:

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ROUND( EXP( SUM( LN( x ) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY y ) ) ) AS z
FROM   table_name t
```

**Output**:

```
Y  |  X |  Z
:- | -: | -:
a  |  2 |  4
a  |  2 |  4
b  |  3 |  3
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=83c4ff12f195945adbff8ff4e6f4c25d)*

Although you could also use `LOG` by specifying the base:

```
EXP( SUM( LOG( EXP(1), x ) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY y ) )
```